# Why can't I display a unicode character in the Python Interpreter on Mac OS X Terminal.app?

Tags: python, unicode, macos, terminal

If I try to paste a unicode character such as the middle dot:

·

in my python interpreter it does nothing. I'm using Terminal.app on Mac OS X and when I'm simply in in bash I have no trouble:

```
:~$ ·
```

But in the interpreter:

```
:~$ python
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Feb 11 2010, 00:51:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

^^ I get nothing, it just ignores that I just pasted the character. If I use the escape \xNN\xNN representation of the middle dot '\xc2\xb7', and try to convert to unicode, trying to show the dot causes the interpreter to throw an error:

```
>>> unicode('\xc2\xb7')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have setup 'utf-8' as my default encoding in sitecustomize.py so:

```
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
```

What gives? It's not the Terminal. It's not Python, what am I doing wrong?!

This question is not related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918294/python-unicode-in-mac-os-x-terminal), as that indivdiual is able to paste unicode into his Terminal.

Comment: I have the same problem, but the default encoding is ascii (dunno why) :((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unicode('\xc2\xb7')` means to decode the byte string in question with the default codec, which is ascii -- and that of course fails (trying to set a different default encoding has never worked well, and in particular doesn't apply to "pasted literals" -- that would require a *different* setting anyway).  You could use instead u'\xc2\xb7', and see:

```
>>> print(u'\xc2\xb7')
Â·
```

since those are *two* unicode characters of course.  While:

```
>>> print(u'\uc2b7')
슷
```

gives you a single unicode character (of some oriental persuasion -- sorry, I'm ignorant about these things).  BTW, neither of these is the "middle dot" you were looking for.  Maybe you mean

```
>>> print('\xc2\xb7'.decode('utf8'))
·
```

which *is* the middle dot.  BTW, for me (python 2.6.4 from python.org on a Mac Terminal.app):

```
>>> print('슷')
슷
```

which kind of surprised me (I expected an error...!-).

Comment: Wow, if there's someone I want to answer a question about Python when I have one, it's Alex Martelli! Thank you! I own all of your Python books.

Comment: Hrm, all of that worked for me and cleared up some confusion I had on unicode vs utf-8, but I am still not able to paste a unicode character in the python interpreter on Mac Terminal.app. Neither can my co-worker when he uses the default apple shell, but he can with the port version of python I guess it is an application or clipboard issue.

Comment: `u'\xc2\xb7'` is not the same thing as `'\xc2\xb7'.decode('utf8')`/`unicode('\xc2\xb7','UTF-8')`. The former is a Unicode string of two code points (U+00C2 (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX) and U+00B7 (MIDDLE DOT)), the latter evaluates to Unicode string with a single code point (U+00B7 (MIDDLE DOT); its UTF-8 encoding requires two bytes). `u'\uc2b7'` is (as illustrated) something completely different: U+C2B7 (HANGUL SYLLABLE SEUS).

Comment: I think those are Korean characters (someone correct me if I'm wrong). They sound like 'sis'.