# Typing utf-8 characters in python in interactive mode on OS-X

Tags: python, macos, unicode

I am trying to type some spanish character into strings in interactive mode.  For example, `option+e e` to produce 'é' so that I make a statement like `string="él"`.  This works in the terminal, but in python (any version I have installed, of which I have several) it doesn't. It simply produces nothing.  This includes trying to paste in the characters.  It's exactly the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718491/why-cant-i-display-a-unicode-character-in-the-python-interpreter-on-mac-os-x-te), specifically the part about pasting and in his comment to Alex's question, where he points out that Alex's answer doesn't address the question of the failure of copy/paste with regards to utf-8 characters.  How can I do this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the Python interpreter"? I access the Python shell *through* the terminal - how do you do it?

Comment: I think I meant interactive mode.  Changed the question.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. How are you getting to this thing you're calling "interactive mode"?

Comment: Launch Terminal, type `python3`.

Answer (score 3):

The `readline` library that Python uses to read interactive input doesn't accept non-ASCII characters sent by the terminal. This means that either your terminal emulator doesn't provide the characters in the UTF-8 encoding, or readline is not configured to accept UTF-8 input.

Fortunately, readline is used by many popular programs, including the `bash` shell, so there is plenty of information how to get it working. For example, [from this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060825071728278):

> **How do I get UTF-8 input to work correctly?**
>
> - In the Terminal
>     Inspector:
>
>   - In the Emulation section, turn off the Escape non-ASCII
>       characters option.
>   - In the Display section, choose Unicode (UTF-8) as
>       the Character Set Encoding.
> - Add the following line to your `.profile:`
>
>   ```
>   export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
>   ```
> - Add the following lines to your `.inputrc`:
>
>   ```
>   set meta-flag on
>   set input-meta on
>   set output-meta on
>   set convert-meta off
>   ```
> - Apply changes by doing a `source ~/.profile` and a `source
>     ~/.inputrc`.

Answer (score 0):

use `u` before the string literal, to make it an unicode string.

```
string = u"El avión cayó del cielo"
```

if that's not working the problem lies in your editor or terminal, in that case try adding

```
#coding: utf8
```

in any of the first 2 lines of your python program and use a proper editor with unicode support.

Comment: The first suggestion doesn't work, I can't input the character at all into the interpreter.  I'm not sure what you mean in the second suggestion. I'm using the terminal app that comes with OS-X and I can input the characters in the shell, but not in python in interactive mode. I've already changed my default encoding to be 'utf-8' in `sitecustomize.py`.

Comment: Changing the default encoding system wide isn't recommended it may break some libraries.

Comment: **Don't** change default encoding.  What does `import sys; print(sys.stdout.encoding)` say?