# Python, notepad and danish letters

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python unicode in Mac os X terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918294/python-unicode-in-mac-os-x-terminal)

Im using notepad++ to write python programs. When I write in danish we often use æ,ø and å. But in my programs when i print to the screen the letters is not readble.

I have tried this
:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
print "æøæææ"
```

how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script and it works fine on my Linux server via SSH, but on the Windows CMD it is messed up.

```
C:\py>python test.py
├ª├©├ª├ª├ª
```

Sadly, it looks like it will never truly work on Windows (at least the current versions), read more in the comments to the question here: [How to print a unicode string in python in windows cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725249/how-to-print-a-unicode-string-in-python-in-windows-cmd)

Comment: Damn, so Python is not that good anyway !!