# Simple print statement gives UnicodeEncodeError on one of two RPI

Tags: python, unicode, ascii

When I copied my program from one RPI to another I suddenly got a lot of errors in the log file. I have narrowed the problem down to a thing related to danish letters ÆØÅ.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
print("ABC æøå ÆØÅ")  #Danish characters
```

On One of my RasberryPies it gives this error.

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
print("ABC \xe6\xf8\xe5 \xc6\xd8\xc5")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

On the two others i runs perfectly.

Python version Python 3.5.3
Checked danish localization with raspi-config.

## -*- coding   is the correct way

Comment: Hi please provide the code snippet that causes the error. You also might want to consult the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have found a difference between the two systems.
sys.getfilesystemcoding() return 'ANSI_X3.4-1968' on the RPI that fails.
sys.getfilesystemcoding() return 'utf-8' on the RPI that works.
Wondering why there is a difference, how I change it, and if it will take care of the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to define Python source code encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728891/correct-way-to-define-python-source-code-encoding)

Answer (score 1):

Before execute python command, add below lines to your terminal.

```sh
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

Now run `python test.py` in the same terminal.

Or you can add below lines in top of your `test.py` file

```py
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

For more details, please check following question,

- [Python unicode in Mac os X terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/918294/6194097)
- [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9942594/6194097)